# Unable to authorize Salesforce Org using CLI, i have already enabled dev hub in the org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

**I get this error in vscode output**

> Try this:
>   Ensure the file /home/vishal/.sfdx/key.json has the file permission octal value of 600.
>   16:54:28.64 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1

**And in sfdx.log**

> {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Vishal","pid":14500,"level":50,"msg":"Ensure the file /home/vishal/.sfdx/key.json has the file permission octal value of 600.","time":"2019-02-17T11:24:27.506Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"Vishal","pid":14500,"level":50,"msg":"[ false,\n  '{\"message\":\"Invalid file permissions for secret file\",\"status\":1,\"stack\":\"genericUnixKeychainInvalidPerms: Invalid file permissions for secret file\\n    at ALMError (/home/vishal/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/almError.js:44:19)\\n    at isValidFileAccess (/home/vishal/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/keyChain.js:519:24)\\n    at fs.stat (/home/vishal/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/keyChain.js:431:45)\\n    at /home/vishal/.local/share/sfdx/plugins/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20\\n    at /home/vishal/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:285:20\\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)\",\"name\":\"genericUnixKeychainInvalidPerms\",\"warnings\":[],\"action\":\"Ensure the file /home/vishal/.sfdx/key.json has the file permission octal value of 600.\"}' ]","time":"2019-02-17T11:24:27.511Z","v":0}

Comment: Well, did you try what the error asks you to do? Do you have your home directory on a file system that does not support full Unix permissions?

Comment: I gave the permissions but still it did not work. I am using Ubuntu and i don't know how to answer that.
After giving the permission log simply says Permission Denied.